# How to verify my mainboard's name before bios update?

Tags: windows-10, bios, motherboard, flashing

I am pretty sure I have a MSI mainboard [B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B450-GAMING-PRO-CARBON-AC) and due to RAM instability issues I want to try the latest bios. (I am aware of the inherent risk of a BIOS upgrade. I want that ComboAM4PIV2 1.2.0.2 update though.)

I assume I downloaded the right file, as of this writing, the:

- [`7B85v1F4.zip`](https://download.msi.com/bos_exe/mb/7B85v1F4.zip).

Since there are similar named boards around, like the [B450 GAMING PRO CARBON MAX WIFI](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B450-GAMING-PRO-CARBON-MAX-WIFI) I want to make double sure it is the right file as that board offers a `7B85v27` file.

Answer (score 3):

Start a command prompt and execute the command:

```
wmic baseboard get product
```

This will list:

```
Product
B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC (MS-7B85)
```

So you have a `B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC` and not the `MAX WIFI`, so the the right file for you is the [`7B85v1F4.zip`](https://download.msi.com/bos_exe/mb/7B85v1F4.zip).

---

If you want to start a BIOS update from a flash drive, make sure the ROM file is on the root of a FAT32-formatted USB stick and not within a subfolder.

MSI flash tool that is accessible from the board's BIOS does not allow browsing into subfolders. (At best it's the only file on the stick but it's not a requirement.)

I can also confirm that the latest BIOS provides better RAM stability *for me* as I am able with this BIOS to run my four 4 x 8192MB G.Skill RipJaws V DDR4-3200 DIMM CL16-18-18-38 at their official ratings, whereas the older BIOS only allowed settings in the 2666 at maximum.

Your mileage may vary, as unstable memory configuration may have different causes.

Comment: You can also look at the sticker on the motherboard itself.  MSI puts a label that identifies the motherboard (serial number, and part number).

Answer (score 2):

Whatever Windows thinks is the motherboard is a good indication,
but not an absolutely sure one.

For example, on my computer the motherboard exact version is not
clearly indicated.

The only sure way is to open the computer case and look for the label
written on the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Windows [System Information](https://www.howtogeek.com/196893/how-to-open-the-system-information-panel-on-windows-8/) panel will show you the computer baseboard manufacturer and product.

[image]